# Does my group generator have to be contained within the group it is generating

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Does the generator always have to be contained within the group. If so, why? Just because those are the rules?

For example, if I have a cyclic group, (Z, +) I can write its presentation as $\langle1\rangle$ - just the generator and no relations. Then if I want to write the presentation for the group of even integers under addition id have $\langle2\rangle$. Will the math police come for me if I just wrote the group as

> $\langle$1 : some relation saying that odds are a no no$\rangle$

I though the whole point of presentation notation was to build up a big mass of stuff with our generators, and shave what we want off using our relations. So why could I not say 1 is my generator for the set of even numbers, it just happens to not be in the group of evens, and when constructing my group using the generator 1 I have to use some relation to only include the even products of the generator.

The reason I ask the question:
I was asked to prove that every subset, H, of some Cyclic group C<sub>n</sub> was also a cyclic group. Well, I knew that all elements of H must also be contained in C<sub>n</sub>, all elements of C<sub>n</sub> are generated by c$\in$ C<sub>n</sub>, and so its pretty clear we can represent any h$\in$H as c<sup>k</sup> for some integer k. So yea, the proof is trivial because c$\in$C<sub>n</sub> generates H. But then we can easily have subgroups where our generator on the group is not contained within the subgroup -- but even still we can represent the new generator on the group as some power of the generator on our overgroup, so why not just call that our generator for the subgroup even if it isn't contained in the group. Could we not just use relations to make everything kosher? Can we not do this because I have a bad understanding of presentations/relations, or just because "them's the rules". Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Yes, the generators of a group are elements of the group.

Comment: can I use a generating element that is not contained within a group, and apply some relation to the set it generates so that it fits my group. E.g. using 1 to generate the group of even integers. 1 is not even, but I can use it to create any even integers under addition, and use some relation to remove the odd numbers generated by 1. Or so I would think

Comment: No.  If $\{g_i\}$ are the generators then the group consists of all the words you can make in those symbols or their inverses.  Of course some of those words represent the same group element, but all of them are group elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generators must be elements of the group, because the definition of a group presentation $\langle S \mid R\rangle$ implies that all elements of $S$ are elements of the group $\langle S \mid R\rangle$.

So your "trivial" proof that a subgroup $H$ of a cyclic group $C_n$ must be cyclic doesn't work. If $c$ generates $C_n$, then $c$ generates *all* of $C_n$. Thus it cannot generate a proper subgroup of $C_n$.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to disagree with your statement that the elements of $S$ are elements of the group $\langle S \mid R \rangle$. The generators of the group are images of $S$ under a homorphism from the free group on $S$ to the group defined by the presentation. Of course it is customary to identify the elements of $S$ (and to use the same symbols) with their images under this homomorphism, but there are times when you need to distinguish between the free group and its image.

Comment: @DerekHolt You're right that I glossed over that. However, in OP's cyclic group example they are simply looking at the subgroup generated by an element, in which case that element must be in the subgroup.